# Tar command in mac os x adding "hidden" files, why?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, tar

I am writing my own tar archiver. All works fine inside my app (even reading tars generated with other tools) however I cannot get my tar files to work with 3rd party tar file readers. So I tried building a tar file on the command line, building one with my code and binary comparing the two.

But there seems to be an issue:

I have a textfile called Test.txt which I want to add to my tar, so I run the following command in the terminal:

```
tar -c -f x.tar Test.txt
```

When doing this:

```
tar -tf x.tar
```

I get the following list:

```
./._Test.txt
Test.txt
```

This is in the Terminal on Mac OS X Lion.

Where does that `./._Test.txt` file come from? I don't see it when doing an ls -a

Upon inspecting the tar contents it seems to be some binary data, but I have no idea where it comes from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a representation of the file's resource fork/extended attributes.

Try `ls -l@ Test.txt` and `xattr -l Test.txt` to see what extra stuff OSX tacked on to the file.

Answer (score 52):

You can add the following to your bashrc file -

```
export COPYFILE_DISABLE=true
```

Or, you can add this option to your `tar` command at the extraction time

```
tar -xzpvf x.tar --exclude="._*"
```

Comment: The exclude parameter does not work here, using the export command does.

Comment: `--exclude` worked for me (after somehow getting into a situation where untarring even on OS X was polluting everything with `._`-files).

Comment: Too greedy in many cases. We want to target COPYFILES not ALL HIDDEN FILES

Answer (score 24):

As of bsdtar `3.0.3 - libarchive 3.0.3` (and perhaps earlier) there's a new (Mac OS X specific) option to the `bsdtar` command called `--disable-copyfile` to suppress the creation of `._` files.

Comment: With `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3` of `10.7.5` the `--disable-copyfile` is not documented but available nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way OSX stores the file system forks when the target file system does not support them.

See: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(file_system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28file_system%29)