# Adding a fat binary framework to Artifactory Cocoapods repository

Tags: ios, cocoapods, artifactory

I'm trying to deploy a fat binary .framework into an Artifactory Cocoapods repository, but I'm receiving an error for podspec parsing shown in the Artifactory logs during the deployment of the .tar.gz file.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Compressed a folder containing FRAMEWORK.framework and the FRAMEWORK.podspec into a FRAMEWORK.tar.gz file (as described in the [written documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories) and shown in the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eiL3IaQG3Q)).
2. Deployed the FRAMEWORK.tar.gz pod up to the Artifactory instance using the curl script described in “Set Me Up”:

   `curl -u<USER>:<PASSWORD> -XPUT
   https://<COMPANY>.jfrog.io/<COMPANY>/cocoapods-local/<FRAMEWORK>/<VERSION>/ -T <FRAMEWORK>.tar.gz`.

The cocoapods-local repo didn’t automatically put the FRAMEWORK.podspec in the .specs folder as shown in the
    video tutorial. In the system logs from Artifactory are lines containing the error:

> 2019-01-14 20:16:29,717 [http-nio-8081-exec-79] [INFO ]
>   (o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:376) - Deploy to
>   'cocoapods-local: FRAMEWORK/FRAMEWORK.tar.gz' Content-Length:
>   27614214
>
> 2019-01-14 20:16:30,278 [http-nio-8081-exec-79] ERROR - Error while extracting
>   metadata from pod: Unable to parse spec.

However, the FRAMEWORK.podspec had passed validation when I used `pod spec lint` from the terminal. The FRAMEWORK.podspec is

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = "<FRAMEWORK>"
  s.version = "<VERSION>"
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.summary = "<Framework>"
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                   <FRAMEWORK>
                  DESC

  s.homepage = "http://www.<COMPANY>.com"
  s.license      = { :type => 'proprietary', :text => <<-LICENSE
                     This software is only permitted to be used
                     by employees of <COMPANY> or
                     of its partners.
                     LICENSE
                   }
  s.author = { "company" => "techadmin@company.com" }
  s.source = { :http => "https://<COMPANY>.jfrog.io/<COMPANY>/cocoapods-local/<FRAMEWORK>/<VERSION>/<FRAMEWORK>.tar.gz", :type => 'tgz'}
  s.preserve_paths = "<FRAMEWORK>.framework*"
  s.vendored_frameworks = "<FRAMEWORK>.framework"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Went through the same issue for days!

Finally found out that the .tar.gz that I was generation on my MacOS machine was using a bsd tar(comes with it by default). Running the same commands from a Linux machine worked!

The one that works is gnu tar. Install it using 'brew install gnu-tar'

Link for using gnu tar : https://medium.com/@fullsour/installing-gnu-tar-on-mac-827a494b1c1

The pod should get pushed to Jfrog artifactory then! :D

Answer (score 1):

I got to this question while unsuccessfully trying to get a pod to be consumable through artifactory. I could see that an extra podspec was shown inside the `tar.gz` I uploaded that looked like `._mypodspec.podspec`. The answer about gnu tar and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766730/tar-command-in-mac-os-x-adding-hidden-files-why) put me on the right track.

It seems that tar on OSX may add extra files to the tarball if it has to store extra file system attributes. In my case tar created an extra hidden podspec file that probably threw artifactory off when attempting to extract the pod information from the artifact.

So I guess an alternative to using gnu tar would be to prefix the tar command with `COPYFILE_DISABLE=1` as shown in the [the above question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766730/tar-command-in-mac-os-x-adding-hidden-files-why) like this:

`COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -zcvf...`

Answer (score 0):

Deploy compiled framework in Jfrog artifactory

https://github.com/awasthi027/Xcode_lib_framework_issues/blob/master/JfrogArtifactory/README.md