# Create tar file on mac but exclude hidden files

Tags: macos, tar, hidden-files

Im using a Mac, trying to create a tarfile which exludes all hidden files (e.g. .file)
I've tried the following, but each time it includes hidden files:

```
 tar --exclude='.*' -czvf  test.tgz .
 tar --exclude='.[^/]*' -czvf  test.tgz .
```

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax which will help me resolve this?

Many thanks

Comment: *"Linux on a Mac"*? Do you mean **VirtualBox**?

Comment: Dunno, uname -a returns Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0:  root:xnu-4903.278.35~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: Try using a space instead of `=`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9665/create-tar-archive-of-a-directory-except-for-hidden-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tar command in mac os x adding "hidden" files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766730/tar-command-in-mac-os-x-adding-hidden-files-why)

Comment: Can you go back a directory `cd ..` and try `tar --exclude='.*' -czvf  test.tgz dir-name`